# Error in state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am working with Redux in React. I had define action & reducer in program. I want to change state by onClick event but its not changing.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const display = (state=0, action) => {
  switch (action.type){
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state+1;
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state-1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = createStore(display);

store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT'});

var ReduxApp = React.createClass({

  plus(){
    return store.dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT'});
  },

  minus(){
    return store.dispatch({type: 'DECREMENT'});
  },

  render(){

    return(
      <div>
        <h1>{store.getState()}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.plus}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.minus}>-</button>
      </div>
    );
  },
});

module.exports = ReduxApp;

store.subscribe(() => render(<ReduxApp />));
```

I tried with subscribe method & re-rendered but its not working.

Comment: Can you show your subscribe & re-rendering code?

Comment: I edited the code. Please look at it. @MichelleTilley

Comment: The code `store.subscribe()` and `this.render()` should not be called where you're calling it.

Comment: @limelights ok. Then where should I call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you haven't connected the rendering to your Redux store, but you're close.

To connect it manually you'd write something like this

```
store.subscribe(() => render(<MyComponent />, document.querySelector('#container'));
```

Using your example this should *not* happen from within the component but from the outside.

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({});
store.subscribe();
```

In a real world scenario you would use something like react-redux and it's Provider component in order to connect the store to your React application.

Comment: ok.Thanks. I changed my code.please look at it. & I am getting error ' render is not defined'.

Comment: Copy-pasting code isn't always helpful - change `render` to `React.render`.

Comment: getting error. If u can elaborate more, it would be helpful

Comment: http://jsbin.com/cupatodiyi/edit?html,js,console,output - This is a working example. I don't know why you're not rendering with `React.render()` or `ReactDOM.render`.

Comment: I did changes what you told. but still I am getting this error:Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.